# How does spl_autoload_register work in Netbeans Todo sample php App?

Tags: php, class, netbeans, spl-autoload-register

I am looking at the sample code of Todo App in Netbeans. Can anyone explain me the use of spl_autoload_register function here:

This is the autoload function

```
public function loadClass($name) {
        $classes = array(
            'Config' => '../config/Config.php',
            'Error' => '../validation/Error.php',
            'Flash' => '../flash/Flash.php',
            'NotFoundException' => '../exception/NotFoundException.php',
            'TodoDao' => '../dao/TodoDao.php',
            'TodoMapper' => '../mapping/TodoMapper.php',
            'Todo' => '../model/Todo.php',
            'TodoSearchCriteria' => '../dao/TodoSearchCriteria.php',
            'TodoValidator' => '../validation/TodoValidator.php',
            'Utils' => '../util/Utils.php',
        );
        if (!array_key_exists($name, $classes)) {
            die('Class "' . $name . '" not found.');
        }
        require_once $classes[$name];
    }
```

here init function declares loadClass in order to load the classes.

```
public function init() {
        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
        mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
        set_exception_handler(array($this, 'handleException'));
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loadClass'));
        // session
        session_start();
    }
```

Here init is called and spl_autoload_register calls loadClass.

```
$index = new Index();
$index->init();
```

My question is how does it load all classes in the $classes array since $name is not defined or passed as a parameter?

Comment: Not defined or used? It's the `loadClass()` parameter and it's used three times, isn't it? :-?

Comment: there is no parameter when the function is called here : spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loadClass'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, when a given piece of functionality allows you to pass a callback function to be called later, the function signature (arguments and return type) is already set by such feature. You can think of it as an API call: you read the docs and provide the expected data. Period.

In this case, the SPL autoloader [expects this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php):

> `void spl_autoload ( string $class_name [, string $file_extensions = spl_autoload_extensions() ] )`

In other words:

- Your function receives the class name as mandatory first argument
- It receives a file extension as second argument, but it's optional to capture it
- It isn't expected to return anything

This is a predefined signature: you don't need to specify when you register the callback function because it isn't possible to change it.